# Pass a value to access object - Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a number in $_id, after $group finished.

But, i need this value to access a object and returns your string.

```js
const week = {
  1: 'Domingo',
  2: 'Segunda',
  3: 'Terça',
  4: 'Quarta',
  5: 'Quinta',
  6: 'Sexta',
  7: 'Sábado',
}

db.trips.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          $dayOfWeek: "$startTime"
        },
        qtd: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    
    {
      $project: {
        diaDaSemana: week["$_id"],
        total: "$qtd",
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

I'm tried so much times, but not works.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation pipeline doesn't dereference objects the same way as javascript.

If you pass in days as an array, in the `$project` stage, you could use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html#arrayelemat-aggregation) to get the corresponding string.

You will need a zero-th element to offset the index so that "Domingo" is at index 1:

```
const week = [
  'Nada',
  'Domingo',
  'Segunda',
  'Terça',
  'Quarta',
  'Quinta',
  'Sexta',
  'Sábado',
]
```

Then in the `$project` stage:

```
    diaDaSemana: {$arrayElemAt: [week, "$_id"]},
```

Comment: Thank You! It Works. I Create an Array with index 0 is ' ', and made the the same way you showed me. Thanks a lot.